# XPath - Find similar, but containing non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to search from an xml document for a text, which with non-aplhanumeric characters removed matches the input text. For example:

Text to search: "sometext"

```
<xml>
  <elem>sometext</elem>    <- match
  <elem>some text</elem>   <- match
  <elem>some.text</elem>   <- match
  <elem>someetext</elem>   <- no match
</xml>
```

Is this achievable with xpath?

Comment: XPath exists in different versions from XPath 1.0 since 1999 to XPath 3.1 since 2017. Which version can you use? XPath 2 and later support more powerful string operations based on regular expressions. Even in XPath 1 it is usually doable, you just need to use the `translate` function to remove anything from elem you don't want to be included e.g. for that simple example `/xml/elem[translate(., ' .', '') = 'sometext']`

Comment: Thanks, translate should do it. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath 1, for simple requirements you can use the `translate` functions to strip characters, e.g. `/xml/elem[translate(., ' .', '') = 'sometext']`. In XPath 2 and later you have the regular expression support with `replace` which might be more powerful if you need to deal with more than ASCII letters for example `/xml/elem[replace(., '[^\p{L}\p{N}]+', '') = 'sometext']`.